# App Insights memory leak in background tasks

Tags: asp.net-web-api, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, background-process, appinsights

I am using Simple Injector DI in .NET web api (.net 4.8 framework) and have a wrapper class(my own implementation) around the telemetry client.

```
public class MyAppInsights : IMyAppInsights
{
private static TelemetryClient telemetry;
public MyAppInsights ()
{
if (telemetry == null)
{
telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
}
}
//other interface method implementations
}
```

simple injector startup configuration looks like

container.Register<IMyAppInsights , MyAppInsights >(Lifestyle.Singleton);

I am noticing lots of Httpwebrequest objects (app insights) are being added to memory and not released for a long running background tasks. This problem appeared only recently after implementing long running background tasks which was causing out of memory exceptions.

Any pointers on how to reduce/plug the memory leak / consumption would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove Lifestyle.Singleton to see if you still have memory leak.
Also check the site for example.

https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: I tried that as well that did not make any difference.